# how to call builtin-productPackagingUtility in command line

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, entitlements

When you specify an entitlement and a code signing identity in build settings (Xcode 4.2.1), you have the following output when you build from Xcode:

```
ProcessProductPackaging "myAppName.entitlements" "/path/to/myAppName.xcent"
cd /path/to/myAppName/SourceCode
builtin-productPackagingUtility "/path/to/myAppName/SourceCode/myAppName.entitlements" -entitlements -format xml -o "/path/to/myAppName.xcent"


CodeSign "/path/to/Garfields Comic Boom 1.0.app"
cd /path/to/myAppName/SourceCode
setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE /Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign "myCertificate" --entitlements "/path/to/myAppName.xcent" "/path/to/myAppName.app"
```

I would like to sign my app folder at the end of the build, and not during the Xcode build.

My problem is I don't know how to generate the xcent file in the command line.

**Question : How do you generate xcent files in command line?  I did a find from the root, there is nothing called productPackagingUtility...**

Comment: One starting point for further analysis might be the file (Xcode 4.4): `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/Framewor‌​ks/DevToolsCore.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/Code Sign.xcspec` (see section with `CommandLine = "builtin-productPackagingUtility [...]`).  Xcode probably instantiates the class `XCWorkQueueCommandBuiltinInvocation_productPackagingUtility` to run this task (it's the only class with a `productPackagingUtility` suffix: `nm /[...]/DevToolsCore.framework/Versions/Current/DevToolsCore | grep -i productPackagingUtility`).

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to sign my app folder at the end of the build, not during the Xcode build.

IIRC recent versions of Xcode complain if you disable code signing for a device build.

The easiest way around this is to let Xcode sign it and then re-sign it later. Steps are approximately

1. Dump the original entitlements with `codesign -d --entitlements=MyApp.xcent MyApp.app`
2. If you're changing provisioning profiles, copy the new one to `MyApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision` and modify the entitlements accordingly (IIRC the file format has a 4-byte magic and a 4-byte length; remember to update the length!).
3. Re-sign with your desired certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Using the codesign utility does not require an xcent file. You can simply create a plist file and use that for entitlements. Make sure it is an XML plist, not binary.

Answer (score 0):

The format of the .entitlements and the ${APPNAME}.xcent is the same so it can just be copied across.