# On Travis CI how are iOS apps code signed and uploaded to Apple TestFlight?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, travis-ci, testflight

I've been trying to setup Travis CI as a build server, but am running into problems both code signing the app, and uploading it to TestFlight.

The main issue is uploading to Apple TestFlight. I can find a lot guides online on how to upload to the old version of TestFlight at testflightapp.com, but I've not figured out how to upload to iTunes Connect.

I attempted to use the `altool` command:

```
altool --upload-app -f "$OUTPUTDIR/$APP_NAME.ipa" -u '$ITUNES_CONNECT_USERNAME' -p '$ITUNES_CONNECT_PASSWORD'
```

But on Travis CI it doesn't work:
`altool: command not found`

-

I've primarily used the following tutorials to get this far: http://www.raywenderlich.com/109418/travis-ci-tutorial and https://www.objc.io/issues/6-build-tools/travis-ci/#app-signing

This is a useful official page:
http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/objective-c/

-

This is my project setup:

**.travis.yml** file:

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode7.1
xcode_workspace: XXXXXXX.xcworkspace
xcode_scheme: XXXXXXX
env:
  global:
  - APP_NAME="XXXXXX"
  - DEVELOPER_NAME="iPhone Distribution: XXXXXXX (XXXXXXX)"
  - PROFILE_NAME="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  - ITUNES_CONNECT_USERNAME="XXXXXX@XXXXXX.com"
  - secure: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
before_script:
- ./scripts/add-key.sh
- ./scripts/update-bundle.sh
script:
- xctool -workspace XXXXXXX.xcworkspace -scheme XXXXXXX -sdk iphoneos -configuration
  Release OBJROOT=$PWD/build SYMROOT=$PWD/build ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=""
  CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
after_success:
- ./scripts/sign-and-upload.sh
after_script:
- ./scripts/remove-key.sh
```

Note that the `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO` on the end of the build command is there because otherwise the app fails to build (see https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/3047 for details, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/11647504/404409 for more info on it). This is probably a cause of the code signing issue described below.

The **add-key.sh**, **sign-and-upload.sh** and **remove-key.sh** scripts are basically just copied direct from https://www.objc.io/issues/6-build-tools/travis-ci/#add-scripts

With the exception of this line being added the end of **sign-and-upload.sh**:

```
altool --upload-app -f "$OUTPUTDIR/$APP_NAME.ipa" -u '$ITUNES_CONNECT_USERNAME' -p '$ITUNES_CONNECT_PASSWORD'
```

-

The app builds, but this is the output from the **sign-and-upload.sh** script at the end:

```
env SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/PackageApplication /Users/travis/build/XXXXXX/ios/build/Release-iphoneos/XXXXXXX.app -o /Users/travis/build/XXXXXX/ios/build/Release-iphoneos/XXXXXXX.ipa -sign iPhone\ Distribution\=XXXXXXXXXXXX -embed /Users/travis/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/XXXXXXXXXXX.mobileprovision
error: Failed to read entitlements from '/var/folders/my/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/X/XXXXXXXXX/Payload/Kimono.app'
./scripts/sign-and-upload.sh: line 20: altool: command not found
```

-

If you have any clues as to how iOS apps should be done on Travis CI, or how to submit builds to TestFlight over the command line I would be eternally grateful!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine, there is no `altool` in my PATH, but `xcrun altool` works. Maybe try that?