# Cordova Hybrid app : export IPA file

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, xcode8

how can we export our project's ipa file? i dont have a paid apple developer membership. My XCode version is 8.

Comment: Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html
OR
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730051/how-to-build-an-ipa-without-signing-in-xcode-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i did it in XCode 8.
Refer to 
[How to create ipa in xcode 6 without Apple Developer account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928721/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6-without-apple-developer-account?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Create Archive

Go to Organizer

Get location of Archive by Right Click and selecting Show in Finder

Now right click on this .xcarchive file and select Show Package
   Contents

Go to path Products > Applications > YourAppFile

Open iTunes's on Mac and drag-drop this YourAppFile from above path
   in Apps tab. (NOTE: Delete the previous app with the same identifier
   if any)

Now right click on your app under Apps tab of iTunes and select Show
   in Finder, this is your .ipa file !!!

Answer (score 0):

To export an .ipa file you must have developer account it is required

Comment: Of course but after getting the developer account what is the process ?

Comment: After getting the developer account you need to generate the signed cert and by using that u need to create the provisional profiles for development and distribution and u need to download that and u also have to create a bundle identifier which should be attached to that particular provisional profile                1. CSR/cert generation --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGqeNbUM0oY

Comment: Could u add more resources I mean how can we generate and process the ipa file