# Is it possible to generate unsigned iPA using Xcode 10.2.1

Tags: ios, react-native

I have followed various tutorials and sites like ([How to build an IPA without signing in Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730051/how-to-build-an-ipa-without-signing-in-xcode-8), [Building iOS applications using xcodebuild without codesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034133/building-ios-applications-using-xcodebuild-without-codesign), https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EID0TTxnxjA, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4kelBsxZVs) to generate unsigned IPA, but did not able to generate iPA. below are the my target and project build settings
[image: Project build setting]

[image: Target build setting]

[image: General info]

[image: sdksetting]

**NOTE: It's a project of React Native.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Step 1:

Set ‘Code Signing Identity’ = ‘Don’t Code Sign’
· Select Targets (‘’) -> Build Settings and find the ‘Signing’ section.
· Set ‘Code Signing Identity’ = ‘Don’t Code Sign’

> Setp 2:

Set Bundle Identifier = ‘com.testCompany.prjectname’
Set Version = 1.0
Set Build = 5
Remove ‘Automatically manage singing’ flag.

> Step 3:

Open terminal and go to the project root folder. Then run the following command.

```
xcodebuild -workspace <projectName>.xcworkspace -scheme <projectName> -configuration Release clean archive -archivePath buildArchive/<projectName>.xcarchive CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=”” CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

> Step 4:

After successfully completing above command, it will create a new ‘.xcarchive’ file inside ‘buildArchive’ folder ( the ‘buildArchive’ folder create inside your project folder)
Zip that ‘.xcarchive’ file and send it to your team agent.

Comment: Thanks@Vinod  I am not getting  ‘Don’t Code Sign’ in ‘Code Signing Identity’ drop down, Do I have click on other and have type it Manually?

Comment: Let me try with this , I will update you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: if you think, my answer is useful for you then please vote up and accept it.@kalpa

Comment: @VinodKumar I can't set the ‘Code Signing Identity’ = ‘Don’t Code Sign’ here!!