# How to run the xcodebuild command on multiple projects, but apply different signing rules to each

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, azure-pipelines, xcodebuild

The Xcode command I'm running is as follows:

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release -workspace ***.xcworkspace -scheme TPE-Stage build CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=\*\*\*IDENTITY HERE\*\*\* PROVISIONING_PROFILE=\*\*\*UUID HERE\*\*\* PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER=
```

Which seems to fail, because it's signing all projects in the workspace and I get this error for one of the `cocoapods` being signed:

> Code Signing Error: JSONUtilities-iOS9.0 does not support provisioning
>   profiles.

I require it to not sign 2 of the projects (cocoapods and frameworks), but to sign the final one. I've tried to separate them out into multiple commands that I run, but because of dependencies it doesn't like that either.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does your issue only occur in VSTS build or you can reproduce this issue locally? It seems your issue is not related to VSTS.

Comment: The same error also happens locally when I run from command line with manual signing, any idea how I can stop the other projects being signed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours more searching I found the answer! @Ben Flynn supplied the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39901677/3825136

Adding `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED="NO";` inside the project file to the build targets that were complaining did the trick.