# ERROR ITMS-90174: “Missing Provisioning Profile - Apps must contain a provisioning profile in a file named embedded.mobileprovision.”

Tags: ios, xcode, azure-devops, testflight

I've been trying to build an Azure Pipeline that build an iOS project and deploys it to Test-flight for the past few days now. Ive been able to get it to successfully build and produce an `.ipa` but i keep running to this error at the AppStoreRelease@1 task:

```
ERROR ITMS-90174: “Missing Provisioning Profile - Apps must contain a provisioning profile in a file named embedded.mobileprovision.”
```

I have checked multiple similar questions for the past few days but none of the answers seem to solve the problem. So far i have tried `--buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"`. Below is my `.yml`. I've almost given up at this point so any assistance will be a big help.

```
steps:
    - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
        inputs:
            certSecureFile: '$(certSecureFile)'
            certPwd: '$(password)'

    - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
        inputs:
            provisioningProfileLocation: 'sourceRepository'
            provProfileSourceRepository: 'sourcefile.mobileprovision'


    - task: Xcode@5
        inputs:
            actions: 'build'
            scheme: 'Scheme'
            sdk: 'iphoneos'
            packageApp: true
            exportOptions: 'plist'
            exportOptionsPlist: 'ExportOptions.plist'
            signingOption: 'manual'
            signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
            provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
            exportPath: "$(system.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
            args: 'CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=No -UseModernBuildSystem=0'
            configuration: 'Release'
            teamId: 'TeamId'
            exportTeamId: 'TeamId'
            xcWorkspacePath: '**/*.xcworkspace'
            xcodeVersion: 'default' # Options: 8, 9, 10, default, specifyPath

    - task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
            contents: '**/*.ipa'
            targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    - task: AppStoreRelease@1
        inputs:
            authType: 'UserAndPass'
            username: '$(user)'
            password: '$(pass)'
            appIdentifier: 'App Identifier'
            appType: 'iOS'
            ipaPath: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.ipa'
            releaseTrack: 'TestFlight'
            teamId: 'Team ID'
            teamName: 'Team Name'
            fastlaneArguments: 'action increment_build_number'
```

Comment: Are you using distribution provision profiles or development provision profiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Xcode app must be signed and provisioned to run on a device or be published to the App Store. It looks like your ios app is not successfully signed.

I saw you defined `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=No` in the attribute `args` of XCode task. This arguement `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=No` will skip the code signing. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034133/building-ios-applications-using-xcodebuild-without-codesign). You can also check the task log of the Xcode task to see if your app is successfully signed.

You can try removing the arguement `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=No` for Xcode task.

Comment: Thanks, don't know how i missed that